# Bash alias not saving after a session

Tags: bash

so I'm really new to bash, and basically don't know anything...
I tried to make a little alias to view my IP adress, and it works...
but when I close the terminal and open another one and type the command in, it just says it's wrong.
here's my code

`alias whatsmyip="echo $(ifconfig | grep broadcast | awk '{print $2}')"`

Please try to make it simple in the comments so even a baby could understand! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Using `echo $(somecommand)` is an antipattern -- the `echo` and `$( )` basically cancel each other out, so it's better to remove both and just run `somecommand` directly. Also, `$` substitutions are performed inside double-quoted strings, so the `$( )` bit will be evaluated immediately (i.e. when you define the alias, not when you use it). If you remove the `echo $( )` as I recommend, then the `$2` in the `awk` command will similarly be substituted immediately; you need to use `\$2` to delay evaluation until the `awk` command actually runs. Or just use a function instead of an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually your alias are defined in `~/.bash_aliases` and it's loaded in `~/.bashrc`

```
if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi
```

this way they persist sessions.